# Parser Error Message: Could not load type 'MyApplication.Default'

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-applications

sorry for my bad English. 
I am developing a Web Application, all well in Localhost, but when uploading it to the server I get the following error: 'Could not load type' MyApplication.Default '. I have already read through here that changing the "CodeBehind" by the "CodeFile" is solved. But in my case, I change it and I get the following error: 'The file' /MyApplication/Default.aspx.cs 'does not exist.' I tried to upload the whole project without publishing it, that is, without creating the dlls, but then I get another type of errors that should not appear. Also, if my project is a web application I do not understand that I have to upload it as a site. Is there any other solution that is not to change CodeBehind by CodeFile or even if it has to be changed someone knows why then it throws me the second error? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in my bin folder, which I had to remove from my folder to put in root